# Variable Bind no declarada - PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Estoy programando un *PL/SQL* por primera vez, y a la hora de ejecutarlo me dice que hay una variable Bind que no está declarada, pero sí que lo está, sería la variable `vFhfechax`:

Código:

```
DECLARE

vFecha_proceso          VARCHAR2(20);
vFhfechax             T0CIHECP.FHFECHAX%TYPE;
BEGIN

 --INICIALIZAMOS CONSTANTES
vFhfechax:=TO_DATE('31/12/9999','DD/MM/YYYY');

RECUPERAMOS LA FECHA DE PROCESO
  vFecha_proceso:=to_date('&1','dd/mm/yyyy');
 vFhfechax:=vFecha_proceso;
```

¿Por qué pasa esto?

Comment: Como comentario lateral, ¿por qué inicializas la variable a la fecha '31/12/9999' si dos líneas después la asignas de nuevo?

Answer (score 0):

no me da error mas que el type que no lo tengo prueba cambiandole el tipo de dato a  varchar2(20) a la variable vFhfechax para ver si no es ese el problema, en sintaxis todo parece estar OK

```
DECLARE

vFecha_proceso          VARCHAR2(20);
vFhfechax             varchar2(20);--T0CIHECP.FHFECHAX%TYPE;
BEGIN

 --INICIALIZAMOS CONSTANTES
vFhfechax:=TO_DATE('31/12/9999','DD/MM/YYYY');

--RECUPERAMOS LA FECHA DE PROCESO
  vFecha_proceso:=to_date('&1','dd/mm/yyyy');
 vFhfechax:=vFecha_proceso;
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia elvega,  el tipo de dato T0CIHECP.FHFECHAX%TYPE;  debe ser DATE, puedes verificar que sea asi, por lo que no habría ningún problema en dejare el  PL/SQL asi

```
    DECLARE

    vFecha_proceso          VARCHAR2(20);
    vFhfechax             T0CIHECP.FHFECHAX%TYPE;
     BEGIN

     --INICIALIZAMOS CONSTANTES
      vFhfechax:=TO_DATE('31/12/9999','DD/MM/YYYY');


    vFecha_proceso:=to_date('&1','dd/mm/yyyy');
    vFhfechax:=vFecha_proceso;

   end;
```